# Decision tree formatting

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, forest, trees, edge

How can I make the following decision tree legible?

[image]

The code is below:

```
\begin{forest}
for tree={l sep+=.8cm,s sep+=.5cm,shape=rectangle, rounded corners,
    draw, align=center,
    top color=white, bottom color=gray!20}
[Root,edge label={node[midway,left]{z=0}} 
  [Unacceptable,edge label={node[midway,left]{Safety=Low}}   
  ]
    [Split on Doors,edge label={node[midway,left]{Safety=Medium}} 
    [Unacceptable,for children={font=\bfseries},edge label=
    {node[midway,left]{Doors=2}} ]
    [Acceptable,for children={font=\bfseries},edge label=
    {node[midway,left]{Doors=3}} ]   
    [Good,for children={font=\bfseries},edge label={node[midway,left]
    {Doors=4}} ]  
    [Split on Lugboot,for children={font=\bfseries},edge label=
    {node[midway,left]{Doors=5more}}
      [Acceptable,for children={font=\bfseries},edge label=
      {node[midway,left]{Lugboot=Small}} ]  
      [Good,for children={font=\bfseries},edge label={node[midway,left]
      {Lugboot=Medium}} ]  
      [Good,for children={font=\bfseries},edge label={node[midway,left]
      {Lugboot=Big}} ]  
   ]   
 ]  
 [Split on lugboot,edge label={node[midway,left]{Safety=High}} 
 [Split on Persons,for children={font=\bfseries},edge label={node[midway,left]{Small}} 
   [Unacceptable,edge label={node[midway,left]{Persons=2}}   
   ]    
   [Good,edge label={node[midway,left]{Persons=4}}   
   ]    
   [Good,edge label={node[midway,left]{Persons=5more}}   
   ]    
 ]  
 [Vgood,for children={font=\bfseries},edge label={node[midway,left]{Medium}} ]    
 [Vgood,for children={font=\bfseries},edge label={node[midway,left]
 {Big}} ] 
]  
]    
\end{forest}
```

Comment: A mock up of the desired results might help.

Comment: Appropriate tags would have likely yielded at least one solution by now, though a proper MWE would help.

Comment: If part of the question is supposed to concern fitting the tree to the page, this can't be meaningfully answered without a proper MWE as it can't be known what the dimensions of the page are. US letter/ A4? Beamer-slide-size? A3? A5? How big are the margins? What's the default orientation?

Comment: The labels can be sorted out, however, if somebody knows how to complete the example. However, even this isn't guaranteed without a more complete context.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't clear what your constraints are, but the following is certainly legible.

[image: legible version of tree]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    l sep'+=.8cm,
    s sep'+=.5cm,
    rounded corners,
    draw, 
    align=center,
    top color=white, 
    bottom color=gray!20,
  },
  forked edges,
  my label/.style={
    edge label={
      node [midway, below right, align=center] {#1}
    },
  }
  [Root,edge label={node[midway,left]{z=0}} 
    [Unacceptable, my label={Safety=Low} 
    ]
    [Split on Doors, my label={Safety=Medium} 
      [Unacceptable,for children={font=\bfseries}, my label={Doors=2}
      ]
      [Acceptable,for children={font=\bfseries}, my label={Doors=3}
      ]   
      [Good,for children={font=\bfseries}, my label={Doors=4}
      ]  
      [Split on Lugboot,for children={font=\bfseries}, my label={Doors=5more}
        [Acceptable,for children={font=\bfseries}, my label={Lugboot\\=Small} ]  
        [Good,for children={font=\bfseries}, my label={Lugboot\\=Medium} ]  
        [Good,for children={font=\bfseries}, my label={Lugboot\\=Big} ]  
      ]   
    ]  
    [Split on lugboot, my label={Safety=High} 
      [Split on Persons,for children={font=\bfseries}, my label={Small} 
        [Unacceptable, my label={Persons=2}   
        ]    
        [Good, my label={Persons=4}   
        ]    
        [Good, my label={Persons=5more}   
        ]    
      ]  
      [Vgood,for children={font=\bfseries}, my label={Medium} ]    
      [Vgood,for children={font=\bfseries}, my label={Big} ] 
    ]  
  ]    
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```